# Need suggestion for creating a new scheduled process

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, soap, scheduled-tasks

I need suggestions regarding creating a scheduled task in a spring boot application. Our application is an order management portal that helps users with details about an order or a list of orders.

Currently, there is a manual process that is as followed: when a new order comes into the database, the user picks up some information of the order, prepares a doc file of it, and sends it to an external portal through email. That portal sends users a response in the email and the user saves the response in the system through our application. Now we want to automate this process in which instead of going the email route we will make a SOAP call to the external portal(send the doc as an attachment in XML request) and get the response back. For this, I want to write a scheduled process (`@Scheduled`) which will pick up the new orders and make a SOAP call for them.

My question is should I create the scheduled process in the same application or create a new module(a spring boot app) for it. I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot scheduling is very handy, go with it if you can. However if you have multiple instances of the spring application, scheduling will be enabled on all of them making it hard to synchronize who calls what.

Now if you are running multiple instances and assuming you have some sort of load balancer in front of them, than create a separate cron job which will call some endpoint and your load balancer will rout the request to one particular instance.

However in the case with multiply instances, probably the cleanest way is to use some sort of messaging like queues. Then all of the application could subscribe to a topic and your cron can just push notifications to it.